# How to output result of windowed aggregation only when window is finished?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KStream` in which I want to count some dimension of the events. I do it as follows:

```
KTable<Windowed<Long>, Counter> ret = input.groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.of(10, SECONDS)))
  .aggregate(Counter::new, (k, v, c) -> new Counter(c.count + v.getDimension()));
```

I want to have a new `KStream` with those aggregations as events. I can do it easily like this:

```
ret.toStream().to("output");
```

The problem is that every event in "input" topic will produce an event to "output" topic. I would like to publish an event to the output topic only when a window is finished. For example if the window is of one minute, send a single event per key per minute.

I think I can do it like this:

```
ret.toStream().foreach((k, v) -> sendToKafkaTopic("output"));
```

But I wonder if there's a better / more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use new feature of KTable [KTable.suppress](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html#suppress-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed-) in version 2.1

This method allows you get exactly one final result per window/key for windowed computations.

More about `suppres` in [KIP-328](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables)

You can update your implementation with `suppress` like this:

```
KTable<Windowed<Long>, Counter> ret = input.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.of(10, SECONDS)))
        .aggregate(Counter::new, (k, v, c) -> new Counter(c.count + v.getDimension()))
        .suppress(untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()));

ret.toStream().to("output"); // now stream should flush events to the output topic only when the window closes
```

Comment: This looks like  a great solution to what I've been looking for

Comment: seems aggregation with `suppress(..) ` does not propagate messages at all if `grace(..)` method not invoked on `TimeWindows`

Comment: I confirm what observed by Vasiliy Sarzhynskyi If grace () is not specified then no events are emitted at all. I had to setup a configuration like this: .windowedBy ( TimeWindows.of ( Duration.ofMillis ( 1000 ) ).grace ( Duration.ofMillis ( 5000 ) ) )