# Kafka Streams Meatadata request only contains internal topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm running an Kafka Streams app with version 2.1.0. I found after running for some time, my app (63 nodes) will enter ERROR state one by one. Eventually, all 63 nodes are down. 
The exception is :

```
ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager - task [2_2] Failed to 
flush state store KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000014: 
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [2_2] 
Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record 
(key 110646599468 value InterimMessage [sessionStart=1567150872690,count=1] 
timestamp 1567154490411) to topic item.interim due to 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update 
metadata after 60000 ms.
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` 
to avoid this error.
```

I enabled the DEBUG logging and found out that the exception happens when the KStream ask for metadata update for internal topics only but not the destination topic. (`item.interim` is the destination topic)

Normally,

```
[Producer clientId=client-autocreate-StreamThread-1-producer] Sending metadata 
request (type=MetadataRequest, 
topics=item.interim,test-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000014-changelog) 
to node XXX:9092 (id: 7 rack: XXX)
```

But before the exception, it was

```
[Producer clientId=client-autocreate-StreamThread-1-producer] Sending metadata 
request (type=MetadataRequest, 
topics=test-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000014-changelog) 
to node XXX:9092 (id: 7 rack: XXX)
```

Config I have changed:

```
max.request.size=14000000
receive.buffer.bytes=32768
auto.offset.reset=latest
enable.auto.commit=false
default.api.timeout.ms=180000
cache.max.bytes.buffering=10485760
retries=20
retry.backoff.ms=80000
request.timeout.ms=120000
commit.interval.ms=100
num.stream.threads=1
session.timeout.ms=30000
```

I'm really confused. Could anyone help me to understand, why producer will send different Metadata request? And any possible way to solve the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also found this message in the log: `Removing unused topic item.interim from the metadata list, expiryMs 1567162348661 now 1567162348709`. Is topic expiry time the retention time?