# How do I implement buffer config correctly when suppressing output from a windowed KTable?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a windowed `KTable` working as expected, but it is outputting every time a new value is received. I found the `.suppress` operator and it does exactly what I want: output results only at the end of the time window. I have added a `grace` value to my `TimeWindow`, but cannot get `.suppress` to work with the windowed `KTable`. [The answer to this question shows what .suppress should look like.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946013/how-to-output-result-of-windowed-aggregation-only-when-window-is-finished)

It appears to me when reading [Apache's documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Suppressed.html), that `untilWindowCloses` is a method of the Suppressed interface, meaning I can't instantiate a `Suppressed` object, correct? I'm not sure how to implement an interface in this way (in the arguments for `.suppress` on a windowed `KTable`).

I feel like I'm missing something stupid, but I've searched and searched and can't figure it out. Any ideas?

```
TimeWindows window = TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

final KTable<Windowed<String>, GenericRecord> joinedKTable = groupedStream
    .windowedBy(window)
    .reduce(new Reducer<GenericRecord>() {
        @Override
        public GenericRecord apply(GenericRecord aggValue, GenericRecord newValue) {
            //reduce code
        }
    })
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded())); //need help here
```

I am using Eclipse and it's telling me `"The method unbounded() is undefined."` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that there are bugs in `suppress()` in 2.1.x and 2.2.x and you should use `2.3.0` if you use `suppress()`.

Comment: Can you expound on what those are? I’m using Confluent’s platform on version 5.1.2. Not sure what version of KStreams that corresponds to.

Comment: That's AK 2.1.1 -- you should use CP 5.3.0. (cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either statically import [`unbounded()`](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Suppressed.BufferConfig.html#unbounded--), or qualify the reference.

```
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded;
```

or

```
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the second method and I get `References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or 
  above`. I looked that up and it says that you need JDK 8. When I do `java -version` I get `openjdk version "1.8.0_191"`. What gives?

Comment: You'll need to find the option in Eclipse to set your source level appropriately. I haven't used Eclipse in some years, buts its available under Project Structure in IntelliJ. https://i.imgur.com/6e0yauW.png

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I found it under Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level. If I were just running this from the command line, would it use whatever JDK I had installed?